# vsftp and ufw problem

Tags: firewall, ufw, vsftpd

I'd like to be able to activate UFW in order to protect my system, but every time I do, I can't send stuff to my system via vsftp.

If I deactivate UFW everything works fine. If I activate it, I can log into the server (I get the "Welcome" message), but I can't see any of the directories and I can't upload or download anything.

I'm using active FTP. Rules for FTP in UFW are:

```
21/tcp ALLOW IN Anywhere
21/tcp ALLOW OUT Anywhere (out)
21/tcp(v6) ALLOW IN Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp(v6) ALLOW OUT Anywhere (v6) (out)
```

What should I be checking?

Comment: It's been a while since I played with FTPS, but you may need to open port 20 inbound (21 is control; 20 is data). You should not need to open any ports outbound.

Comment: you will need 20 and 21 open if you're serving plain FTP.

Comment: Added Port 20 to the rules.  Didn't change anything.

Comment: I would like to reopen this issue.  I discovered the problem is attempting to connect in "Passive" mode.  I can connect in "Active" mode, but if I connect in "Passive" it cannot access the directories.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I found this page, tried the suggestion and it didn't work.
https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/vsftpd-passive-mod-ubuntu/

Answer (score 4):

Took a LOT of digging, but I found my answer. From [user9517's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/421169) to [How to configure vsftpd to work with passive mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/421161/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-work-with-passive-mode), I added the lines shown to `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_max_port=10100
pasv_min_port=10090
```

(`10090` and `10100` are example ports used in the linked post which I adjusted myself to fit my needs) and restarted the daemon:

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
```

Then, from [How to enable FTP passive mode on Ubuntu vsftpd server](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/vsftpd-passive-mod-ubuntu/)
, I added the range of ports I defined in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` to UFW using the command:

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any proto tcp port 10090:10100
```

Now everything works! Whew!!